# who controls the output.log and error.log files?

Tags: java, logging

my system outputs its logs to a output.log file and error.log file.

What component is responsible for those files ?
(I know platform.log is by log4j )
How do I change the destination folder?

thank you.
EDIT: This is an xml file

Comment: can you post your `log4j` config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be a configuration file for your project , with these entries in it :

```
FILE log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${user.home}/log.out
```

Comment: Hi, I have a log4j xml. There is only one file platfor.log reference. I am guessing output.log and platform.log are directed to the default folder. what should I add ?

Answer (score 1):

On your project, there must be either `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` in the project root directory. In the file, there must be a an appender configuration that points to a `error.log` and `output.log`.

Answer (score 1):

### log4j.properties:

```
# Point logger to two appenders to stdout and R.
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout, R

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=/path/to/logs/output.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

#### Answer to your question is in this line:

```
log4j.appender.R.File=/path/to/logs/output.log
```